# Deployment azure web app with "az webapp deployment source config-zip" works incorrectly

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-cli, azure-deployment, azure-webapps

I have a simple web.api that I want to deply to azure. I use github actions for this.

in case if I use `azure/webapps-deploy@v2` step, all works smoothly.

```
 deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      # published previously via `dotnet publish` and 
      #  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      #   with:
      #     name: webapp
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: webapp
        path: webapp
    - name: Login via Azure CLI
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        # secret in json form are added into repository settings
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    - name: Deploy web app
      id: deploywebapp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        package: webapp
```

I can deploy application and then it's accessible via https://%AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME%.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html. Now, I want to use plain azure CLI commands and replace the above steps on (the only change I do):

```
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: webapp
        path: webapp
    - name: Azure Login
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.30.0
        inlineScript: |
          az login --service-principal \
          -u ${{ secrets.DEPLOYMENT_AZURE_CLIENT_ID }} \
          -p ${{ secrets.DEPLOYMENT_AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET }} \
          -t ${{ secrets.DEPLOYMENT_AZURE_TENANT_ID }}        
    - name: Deploy to Azure WebApp
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.30.0
        inlineScript: |
          zip -r webapp.zip .
          az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_RG }} --name ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }} --src "webapp.zip"
```

this step doesn't fail too, but the deployed application is inaccessible (with previous url) and returns 404 error. The deploy step output is:

```
WARNING: Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
WARNING: Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
WARNING: Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
{
  "active": true,
  "author": "N/A",
  "author_email": "N/A",
  "build_summary": {
    "errors": [],
    "warnings": []
  },
  "complete": true,
  "deployer": "Push-Deployer",
  "end_time": "..",
  "id": "..",
  "is_readonly": true,
  "is_temp": false,
  "last_success_end_time": "..",
  "log_url": "https://%AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME%.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log",
  "message": "Created via a push deployment",
  "progress": "",
  "received_time": "..",
  "site_name": "%AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME%",
  "start_time": "...",
  "status": 4,
  "status_text": "",
  "url": "https://%AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME%.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest"
}

az script ran successfully.
```

What is the difference between both of these steps?

**UPDATE1**: I've added `--debug` argument to `az webapp deployment ..` command and see no errors or failures in the verbose output

**UPDATE2**: I see required files when I `ssh` to the azure server:

```
root@..:~/site/wwwroot/webapp# ls
DeploymentTemplates                 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll  WebApiDemo.deps.json  WebApiDemo.runtimeconfig.json  web.config
Microsoft.OpenApi.dll               Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll   WebApiDemo.dll        appsettings.Development.json
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll  WebApiDemo
```

**UPDATE3**: It looks like it might be related to the fact that when I use a plain CLI commandsm the actually generated files are placed one level deeper (see ssh output before and pay attention on `webapp` folder). Where in the correctly deployed application the deployed files are placed in the root of `wwwroot`:

```
root@..:~/site/wwwroot# ls
DeploymentTemplates                 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll  WebApiDemo.deps.json  WebApiDemo.runtimeconfig.json  web.config
Microsoft.OpenApi.dll               Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll   WebApiDemo.dll        appsettings.Development.json
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll  WebApiDemo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in a zip file. The content inside was:

```
- folderName
  - file1
  - file2
```

which led to the folders structure inside wwwroot:

```
- wwwroot
  - folderName
    - file1
    - file2
```

where the zip content should be just:

```
- file1
- file2
```

Fixing it has solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two tasks is `azure/web-apps-deploy@v2` is copying the files to the underlying storage to `home/site/wwwroot` where as the `az webapp deployment config-zip` copies the zip file to `home/data/SitePackages`. If you have `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1"`, then the platform will mount the zip file in `SitePackages` as the `home/site/wwwroot` directory, otherwise, the contents of the zip file get extracted, which is similar to what `azure/web-apps-deploy@v2` does.

The [diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) will help determine what's causing your app to 404. Based off the information you've provided; I would make sure the zip command is actually zipping the right artifact from `actions/download-artifact@v3`. Since you're zipping the root, you might be zipping the folder instead of the built binaries.

Comment: as far as I can see, the destination folder in both cases is `home/site/wwwroot` where in the "failed" one this path is appended by a zip name. note: I don't configure any configuration other than already mentioned and use default VS templates as code source

Comment: > where in the "failed" one this path is appended by a zip name

In the deployment logs, can you compare the artifacts path? That's what I was referring to; your yaml, you may not picking up the correct path from `azure/download-artifacts@v3` task in your `azure/web-apps-deploy@v2` step.

One thing you could do is configure that task to delete destination files and check the deployment logs for when your code is built to a package and what's being deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue with `az webapp deployment source config-zip`

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/26060